# Keychain not working on Release Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

So I'm having a frustrating issue. I created 3 schemes (Dev, QA, Release). Those 3 changes the configurations with some macros for me to point to 3 different URLs for our API.

The issue I'm having is that my keychain doesn't work for QA and Release (it seems very inconsistent) so when I try to get something from the keychain, nothing ever comes back. I'm now worried about when I submit this for a release that it won't work...any ideas? let me know if I need to explain something more, I probably didn't do a good job explaining

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?" Do you receive an error code? Are you checking for errors? When you say "it seems very inconsistent" do you mean that sometimes it returns a result and sometimes it does not? Posting your code is the usual first step.

Comment: @RobNapier I'm using [KeyClip](https://github.com/s-aska/KeyClip) for Keychain management. I get error 0 sometimes...which I don't get why. it also crashes on a [specific line](https://github.com/s-aska/KeyClip/blob/master/KeyClip/KeyClip.swift#L158)

and yes, sometimes nothing comes back...sometimes it crashes, and sometimes it works...again ONLY during the release scheme

Comment: Have you noted the "!! warning !!" on KeyClip's page indicating they have trouble when compiled with "Fastest" optimization? I'd say this is a known issue for the library.

Comment: and I already changed it to 'None' optimization

Comment: My bad, I changed the "PROJECT" to None, not the target...seems to work now